# Can't publish Android Alpha test because Content rating is "In progress"

Tags: android, google-play

I have completed a questionnaire but still can't publish the Alpha-version as it is "In progress". Am I waiting for some human to verify this (I've been waiting almost 24H), or am I doing something wrong?

When clicking the "Why can't I publish?" link it says:

> Your app is missing a required content rating. Go to your app's Content Rating page and complete a rating questionnaire.

It seems like it is waiting for me to something, but as said, I have completed the questionnaire and clicked "Apply rating to my app.".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am facing the same problem.. how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to be complete all required fields then Rollout button will
>   be enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was waiting for you (make sure you close the questions answered, and then click on 'Calculate...' and then click on 'Apply rating'. Content rating is automatically calculated based on your answers to the questions on the form, and may be reviewed later by a human.